# Why would oracle automatically trim a String's leading zeros on insert or update?

Tags: oracle

I have two tables "Customer" and "Quote", each has a customer_number field that's CHAR(6). Actually, "Quote" is a table, and "Customer" is a view that maps to "Groups" (also CHAR(6)). Database is 11g XE.

I insert "000100" into "Customer", and when I query it, that's what I get. I insert the same exact thing into "Quote", and when I query it, I get "100   " with three trailing empty spaces.

For certainty:

Here's an exerpt from the "CUSTOMER" DDL statement:

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW "SCHEMA"."CUSTOMER" ("CUSTOMER_RSN", "CUSTOMER_NAME", "GROUP_TYPE", "ORGANIZATION_NAME", "MANAGING_GROUP_RSN", "CUSTOMER_NUMBER", ... "LAST_CHANGED_AT") 
AS 
      select GROUPS_RSN, GROUP_NAME, GROUP_TYPE, ORGANIZATION_NAME, MANAGING_GROUP_RSN, CUSTOMER_NUMBER, ... LAST_CHANGED_AT
    from SCHEMA.GROUPS where group_type = 'Customer' WITH CHECK OPTION;
```

Here's an exerpt from the "Groups" DDL statement:

```
CREATE TABLE "SCHEMA"."GROUPS" 
   (    "GROUPS_RSN" NUMBER(6,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "GROUP_NAME" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "GROUP_TYPE" VARCHAR2(40 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "ORGANIZATION_NAME" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "CUSTOMER_NUMBER" CHAR(6 BYTE) DEFAULT '000000' NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "CUSTOMER_CODE" VARCHAR2(4 BYTE), …
     PRIMARY KEY ("GROUP_NAME", "GROUP_TYPE")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 16384 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SCHEMA_IDX"  ENABLE
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 16384 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SCHEMA" ;
```

Here's the code for an update on "Customer":

```
String customer_number = "";  
customer_number = request.getParameter( "customer_number" );

...

logger.debug("Updating the customer_number:" + customer_number );
                        String updateSql =
                                "update oe_customer set " +
                                "customer_name = '" + customer_name "', " +
                                "managing_group_rsn = " + managing_group_rsn + ", " +
                                "customer_number = '" + customer_number + "', " ...
```

Here's the log output from an update on "Customer":

```
21:21:30.861 [http-bio-8080-exec-74] DEBUG org.apache.jsp.updateCustomer_jsp - Updating the customer_number:000100
```

Here's an exerpt from the "Quote" DDL statement:

```
 CREATE TABLE "TIME"."QUOTE" 
   (    "QUOTE_RSN" NUMBER(6,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "QUOTE_NUMBER" NUMBER(6,0), 
    "OE_CUSTOMER_RSN" NUMBER(6,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "CUSTOMER_NUMBER" CHAR(6 BYTE) DEFAULT '000000' NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "CUSTOMER_NAME" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE,   ...    
 CONSTRAINT "UNIQUE_Q_RSN" UNIQUE ("QUOTE_RSN")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 16384 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SCHEMA_IDX"  ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "PK_Q" PRIMARY KEY ("QUOTE_NUMBER")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 16384 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SCHEMA_IDX"  ENABLE
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 16384 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SCHEMA" ;
```

Here's the code for an update on "Quote":

```
newValue.customerNumber is a public String customerNumber;

...
            logger.debug("Updating existing quote, rsn: " + newValue.quoteRSN);
            String updateQuote = "update quote set ";
            try {

                updateQuote += "OE_CUSTOMER_RSN = " + newValue.oe_customerRSN + ", ";
                updateQuote += "CUSTOMER_NUMBER = " + newValue.customerNumber + ", ";
                logger.debug("Updating quote customer_number to:" + newValue.customerNumber);
```

Here's the log output from an update on "Quote":

```
00:50:45.232 [http-bio-8080-exec-73] DEBUG quote.Quote_Single_Record - Updating existing quote, rsn: 86250
00:50:45.232 [http-bio-8080-exec-73] DEBUG quote.Quote_Single_Record - Updating quote customer_number to:000100
```

Here's the values sitting in the database:
[image]

Please help if you have any ideas. Thanks.

Comment: Check the data type of customer_number in table C, it may be number and not char(6).

Comment: [edit] your question and add the `create table` statement for the table. Unrelated, but: do ***not*** concatenate variables into a SQL statement. Use a `PreparedStatement` instead. This will make your application more secure and will improve performance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the statement for Table `QUOTE` newValue.customerNumber isn't quoted.

```
 "customer_number = -->'" + customer_number + "'<--, "
```

vs

```
 updateQuote += "CUSTOMER_NUMBER = " + newValue.customerNumber + ", ";
```

so its a number, and  through the conversion there are no leading zeros.

HINT: Try to use prepared statements, they are safe against errors like this one and SQL injection.

Comment: Very good catch. Even after you pointed it out I had a hard time seeing that, and recognizing its effect. Problem solved, thanks so much.

Comment: to the Editor: Sorry i rejcted the Edit bIefore reading the edited Question, you were right.